# Columns are overlapping in bootstrap 2 layout

Tags: css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using codeigniter and am trying to set up a bootstrap 2 column layout using in my controller:

```
$data['form'] = $this->load->view('sellers/form7','',TRUE);
$data['data1'] = $this->load->view('sellers/lorem','',TRUE);
$this->load->view('sellers/twocolumnlayout', $data);
```

my layout view is :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span5">
 <?php echo $form ?>
</div>
<div class="span2">
</div>
<div class="span5">
<?php echo $text1 ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately my columns are overlapping (Please see attached pic). Can anyone show me how to fix this?

Comment: I would try deleting the empty div (span2) and updating to span6, to have two columns next to each other.

Comment: This is clearly bootstrap V2. It should work (http://jsfiddle.net/HJ59p/4/) though without having the full context. Mark-up of the forms, the page itself ... Hard to debug. By default all columns have a gutter (margin) in bootstrap V2.

Comment: @Teknotica the div[.span2] will get a width. That could not be the culprit.

Comment: True. Make sure that everything it's wrapped up with a div of class "container".

Comment: Teknotica , it is wrapped in a container-fluid, also when I remove the mid column it looks good on a maximized browser but when I start to shrink the window down the overlap occurs - Bill